# Making a custom printing page using Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page which contain different div element

`<body>  <div id="forPrintingHeader" > <div>...</div> </div>
         <div add-div-to-printing-header id="PieChartContainer" >
            <svg id="pieSVG">....</svg> 
        </div
</body>`

`#PieChartContainer` div element contain `svg` element
all things which i want to print is inside `#forPrintingHeader` div element

when i click on  print then  i apply css for body `display:none` and `#forPrintingHeader` div `visibility:visible`

***add-div-to-printing-header*** is directive- it copy a element an add it to another element on same page with modifying some css property --visibility when printing  this div element

```
  AngularPrint.directive('addThisToPrinting', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller:printContoller,
    link: function(scope, element){
        var c=element.clone();
        var b=$('div#forPrintingHeader');//header for printing 
      //apply css @media print { visibility:visible; display:initial;}
        c[0].classList.add('printOnly');   
        c.appendTo(b);//append in header 
      }
    }
  });
```

**but its not working.. I am not able to modify the `DOM` as required**

```
    copy a DOM element and change some css and add  in another DOM Element
```

here selected element `#PieChartContainer` is also modify

may be reason is that

1--id is same (selected element and cloned element)

i dont know how change id of clone element in directive

2-- it is an svg element

please suggest some methods for solving this problem `OR`i am missing something..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'id' add a class and use the class selector in directive instead of Id selector.

Comment: in directive  i am getting element as **element** because i am applying this directive to PieChartContainer i am not selecting it by id..